# How to use setCache for OkHttpClient in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, okhttp

I want to show 3 `fragments` in my `Activity` and load data from **`json`** in any `fragments`! I need to show website data into `Recyclerview` with `OkHTTP v3` library. 
I want to show this data for offline, I mean, if user turn off data/wifi show this datas for **offline**. but i do not want use **SQLite Database**!
For this idea i use **okHttpClient** `cache` , but not found `setCache` for client and show me this Error : [Image link](https://s31.postimg.org/kqwrx9zgr/image.jpg)

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);

        //setup cache
        File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "responses");
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);

        //add cache to the client
        client.setCache(cache);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.learn2crack.com")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                        .build();
            } else {
                int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    };

    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

How can i fix this and use okHttpClient cache?

Comment: I think your gradle of okhttp do not contain setCache method.I think you need to use compatible version of okhttp.

Comment: @Drv, i added this for gradle : `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'` . can you help me ?

Comment: Yeah and so I think the method setCache is of okttp 2. something versions.

Comment: Change this `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'` to this `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'`.

Comment: @Drv, i added this : 'compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'' , but not work me again :(

Comment: Add the above gradle suggested by Ironman.

Comment: @Ironman, when added you gradle code, `setCache` is ok but now not found this : https://s32.postimg.org/78got1azp/image.jpg . please help me my friend

Comment: @Drv, when added you gradle code, setCache is ok but now not found this : s32.postimg.org/78got1azp/image.jpg . please help me my friend

Comment: I think you need to use the oktttp 's compatible version which is suitable for your retrofit2.And I think oktttp's 2. versions are compatible with retrofit1.This links might be useful https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-manage-request-headers-in-okhttp-interceptor